# Include null values and joins properly in query

Tags: sql, join, left-join, oracle-sqldeveloper, self-join

I am using oracle sqldeveloper and I'm trying to generate results that include customer information under certain criteria that is searched by date range. I feel like I am close however I would like to include accounts that apply all the criteria but haven't made payments as well.

My intended result is to look something like this:

```
CYCLENUMB | WOCREATIONDATE | POSTINGDATE | CUSTOMERNUMBER | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | ADDRESS          | WOORDERTYPE | DESCRIPTION | PAYMENT
12        |  29-JUL-20     |  01-AUG-20  |  345506        |  Luke     | Skywalker| 123 Lakeway Dr.  | 636         |Completed    |  $100
24        |  01-AUG-20     |  07-AUG-20  |  456923        |  Leia     | Skywalker| 456 Lakeway Dr.  | 636         |Completed    |  $300
35        |  17-AUG-20     |  24-AUG-20  |  596854        |  Chewy    | Wookie   | 789 Lakeway Dr.  | 636         |Completed    |  NULL
80        |  21-AUG-20     |  28-AUG-20  |  695067        |  Han      | Solo     | 432 Wrongturn Dr.| 636         |Completed    |  NULL
66        |  25-AUG-20     |  30-AUG-20  |  235645        |  Count    | Dooku    | 534 Wrongturn Dr.| 636         |Completed    |  $225
```

However my results are coming out just like this

```
CYCLENUMB | WOCREATIONDATE | POSTINGDATE | CUSTOMERNUMBER | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | ADDRESS          | WOORDERTYPE | DESCRIPTION | PAYMENT
12        |  29-JUL-20     |  01-AUG-20  |  345506        |  Luke     | Skywalker| 123 Lakeway Dr.  | 636         |Completed    |  $100
24        |  01-AUG-20     |  07-AUG-20  |  456923        |  Leia     | Skywalker| 456 Lakeway Dr.  | 636         |Completed    |  $300
66        |  25-AUG-20     |  30-AUG-20  |  235645        |  Count    | Dooku    | 534 Wrongturn Dr.| 636         |Completed    |  $225
```

Below is the query I'm trying to run

```
select customermaster.cyclenumber  as CYCLENUMB, 
   workorder.creationdate as WOCREATIONDATE,
   MAX(cushistory.postingdate) as POSTINGDATE,
   cushistory.customernumber as CUSTOMERNUMBER,
   customerpersonalinfo.firstname as FIRSTNAME,
   customerpersonalinfo.lastname as LASTNAME,
   premiseaddress.Concatenated_Address  as ADDRESS,
   workorder.ordertype as WOORDERTYPE,
   workorderstatus.description as DESCRIPTION,
   SUM(cushistory.moneysegment1) as PAYMENT
from   customermaster, workorder, customerpersonalinfo,
   (select
          premiseaddress.company  as  COMPANY,
          premiseaddress.premisenumber  as PREMISENUMBER,
          ((to_char(premiseaddress.currpremisestreetnumber) || ' ') || premiseaddress.currpremisestreetname)  as  Concatenated_Address
    from premiseaddress)
          premiseaddress, workorderstatus,  cushistory

where workorder.ordertype = 636
      and cushistory.moneytypecode1 = 7
      and workorder.application = 3
      and cushistory.postingdate between '01-Aug-20' and '31-Aug-20'
     and customermaster.customernumber = cushistory.customernumber
     and cushistory.customernumber = workorder.customernumber
     and customermaster.company = workorder.company
     and customermaster.accounttype = workorder.application
     and customermaster.customernumber = workorder.customernumber
     and workorder.application = workorderstatus.application
     and workorder.completecode = workorderstatus.workorderstatus
     and customermaster.company = customerpersonalinfo.company
     and customermaster.occupantcisnumber =customerpersonalinfo.cisnumber
     and customermaster.company = premiseaddress.company
     and  customermaster.premisenumber = premiseaddress.premisenumber
 GROUP BY customermaster.cyclenumber,
      workorder.wocreationdate ,
      cushistory.postingdate,
      customermaster.customernumber,
      customerpersonalinfo.firstname,
      customerpersonalinfo.lastname,
      premiseaddress.Concatenated_Address,
      workorder.ordertype,
      workorderstatus.description
  ORDER BY workorder.creationdate asc
```

I included a subquery for simplifying customer address. Postingdate from cushistory is the date range filer I am applying.

Please note that custhistory table is the main table that holds customernumbers and payments. I wanted to left join it with workorder table to include null values but haven't figured out a surefire way to do it.

Comment: The problem is you are using old style implicit joins, i.e. where you have comma separated the tables and have *all* your conditions (join and filter) in the where clause. This is far from best practice, and causes the issues you are seeing now. Instead use proper defined joins, inner and left, with on clauses for the join conditions, and filter conditions in your where clause. This will give you the result you want.

Comment: That clarifies thing thanks for the advice. I have tried to restructure the query but im still kinda unfamiliar on how to go about it and which conditions would go into which join. Also how would I join my subquery?

Comment: Can I suggest checking out some tutorials on joins... I can't explain in a comment and I don't have time to re-write your entire query. Join conditions are usually just your PK/FK relationship. You join a sub-query in exactly the same way. But there are 1000's of example and tutorials out there.

Comment: Okay I will be sure to check some tutorials out as well as look at more examples. Thanks for your time and suggestions its greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you are using SQL-89 joins (was that the year of the lambada?). It would be much simpler to use SQL-92 joins.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: @DaleK Comma means cross join but with lower precedence than keyword JOINs. So the JOIN ON is done first & the left table of the comma is not known there. And the precedence can confuse readers. But when names are not used out of scope & no outer joins are involved, the result is the same as using CROSS JOIN instead of comma & whether a text is in ON or WHERE doesn't matter. Also these equivalences are trivial for the simplest optimizers to generate the same code for. So your "The problem is [...]" & "This will give you the result you want" are wrong.